# SSH into multiple servers and compare timestamps of each server

Tags: bash

I need to add the timestamp of all remote servers as part of output and check & compare whether the timestamp is the same or not,

I am able to print the machine IP and date.

```
#!/bin/bash

all_ip=(192.168.1.121 192.168.1.122 192.168.1.123)

for ip_addr in "${all_ip[@]}"; do
  aws_ip=$"ip route get 1 | sed -n 's/^.*src \([0-9.]*\) .*$/\1/p'"
  date=date
  sshpass -p "password" ssh root@$ip_addr "$aws_ip & $date"
  echo "==================================================="
done
```

> Getting Output as :

```
Wed 27 Jul 2022 05:48:15 AM PDT
192.168.1.121
===================================================
Wed Jul 27 05:48:15 PDT 2022
192.168.1.122
===================================================
Wed Jul 27 05:48:15 PDT 2022
192.168.1.123
===================================================
```

How to check whether the timestamp ( **ignoring seconds** ) of all machines is the same or not ,

eg: (Wed 27 Jul 2022 05:48:15 || Wed 27 Jul 2022 05:48:15 || Wed 27 Jul 2022 05:48:15)

Expected Output:

```
|| Time are in sync on all machines || # if in sync

|| Time are not in sync on all machines || # if not sync

Wed 27 Jul 2022 05:48:15 AM PDT
192.168.1.121
===================================================
Wed Jul 27 05:48:15 PDT 2022
192.168.1.122
===================================================
Wed Jul 27 05:48:15 PDT 2022
192.168.1.123
===================================================
```

Comment: I suggest to choose a different format for the date output that is easier to compare, e.g. `date +%s` (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC). You should also consider that a small difference might be expected the `date` commands will not run at exactly the same time. When you have more than 2 machines, the statement "Date/Time are different on all machines" is not exactly the same as "Date/Time are not the same on all machines".

Comment: Are you using ntpd or chronyd or something else? Are all your machines syncing to the same time servers?

Comment: @jhnc using crontab for date-time sync  date --set= ""  to setup the time through ansible

Comment: @rowoc No, I can't. I don't know who downvoted the question. Ignoring seconds is not sufficient. Even the year can change in a millisecond. The command might get executed at Dec 31 2022 23:59:59 (and 999 msec) on one machine and at Jan 1 2023 00:00:00 (and 1 msec) on the other machine. That's why I suggest to compare the output of `date +%s`. You could check if the difference between the maximum and minimum value is above a small limit.

Comment: @Bodo Ya I agree to your point, but I can consider that small difference if it now match then it should echo " Date and Time are not in sync" .

Comment: Please clarify in your question what output you expect. The output below "Getting Output as" followed by one of the lines about "in sync" or not? Or only the line about "in sync" or not?

Comment: Is the goal here to prove that your machines all have the same time on them, so that if they are not you can adjust them? If so, consider setting up a cron job to sync with an NTP server and then you don't have to think about it.

Comment: Only concern with your approach would be the authentication time and starting one of the first hosts on `hh:mm:59` and having the date command or next host check occur at `hh:mm+1:00`, etc..

Comment: @Bodo Updated the expected output : It should print the sync / not sync message as addition to my existing output

Comment: @AndyLester Ya if time are in sycn still sometime machine date got change , to motinter that I required this implimentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to check whether the time ( ignoring seconds )

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
trap 'rm -r "$tmpdir"' EXIT
for ip in "${allips[@]}"; do
  # Do N connections, in paralllel, each one writes to a separate file.
  sshpass -p "password" ssh root@"$ip" "date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M" > "$tmpdir/$ip.txt" &
done
wait

times=$(
  for i in "$tmpdir"/*.txt; do
     # print filename with file contents.
     echo "$i $(<$i)"
  done |
  # Sort them on second column
  sort -k2 | 
  # Uniq on second field
  uniq -f 2
)
echo "$times"
timeslines=$(wc -l <<<"$times")
if ((timeslines == 1)); then
   echo "YAY! minutes on all servers the same"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you may adjust your "date" command as folow in order to exclude the seconds:

```
date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M
```

Then, simply grep your output and validate that all the timestamps are identical. You may dump in a temporary file or any other way.
Ex:

```
grep [aPatternSpecificToTheLinewithTheDate] [yourTemporaryFile] | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

If the result is 1, it means that all the timestamps are identical.
However you will have to deal with the corner case where the minute shift while you are fetching the time form all your servers.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as `date '+%F_%R'`?

Comment: Yes, nice shortcut, thanks.